# How to correctly transfer background-image property in CSS in to HTML code without disrupting other CSS property?

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

**I first used 'background-image' CSS property in a div to display the image due to the fact that it displays it properly as I wanted it:**

1. The image is below the nav bar (allowing the shadow to be shown).
2. The image is an edge to edge but only accommodate less than 30% of the
   screen height according to the user screen size.
3. The image allows a semi-transparent overlay for a title and
   description of the image.
4. The image will fill(crop) to fit the canvas instead of stretching
       out or shrink.

**How do I transfer the 'background-image' CSS property in to HTML as  tag?** As CSS doesn't support alt text as they're required for me to pass the exam.

> I've tried to add a  tag into HTML and removed background-image
>   property from HTML (also ruleset name to accommodate the added img
>   tag)  However, it doesn't display it correctly as I wanted it to be.

**== THE CODE ==**

**Old code:**
CSS:

```
.image-container {
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 48vw;
    min-height: 380px;
    max-height: 550px;
    background-image: url('/assests/DisplayImage.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;

.image-container .detail {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="image-container">
        <div class="=detail">
            <h1>
                Title text
            </h1>
            <h3>
                Description
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**New Code:**
HTML:

```
    <div class="image-container">
      <img scr=/assests/DisplayImage.jpg>
        <div class="=detail">
            <h1>
                Title text
            </h1>
            <h3>
                Description
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS: (.image-container .detail remain the same)

```
.image-container img{
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 48vw;
    min-height: 380px;
    max-height: 550px;
    position: relative;
}
```

**I expect it to be like this:**
[Expected (original result)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUHH5.png)
**Instead I got this:**
[The result of changing the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttiLZ.png)

***In addition to this, I also wanted my image to be focused on the center of the image when the screen is resized instead of just cropping the bottom.***

Thank you. This might be too specific, but I'm sure that this will help those who also used a CSS background image instead of HTML tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jjPgbx) 

 There's nothing wrong in your code as I see. 

For aligning image to center use

```
 background-position: center;
```

If you are using img tag for image use below properties.

```
object-fit: cover;
object-position: bottom;
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for that. However, I need to use HTML <img>  because I need to use alt text to be able to compete the assignment.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the pen, by replacing bg with img. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using background image ?
You can use this

```
 <img src="// url " alt ="// text">
```

And then the css

```
img {
//css
}
```

Comment: As in the question, I tried it and for some reason other CSS properties breaks ( see https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttiLZ.png )